# How to resolved error "must declare the scalar variable @var" in call stored procedure by EF?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want to execute stored procedure uses entity framework and return result list of my model type :

My stored procedure in DB is :

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].myProc
(
    @myParam1 int,
    @myParam2 nvarchar(max)   
)
as
BEGIN
    SELECT myCol1,myCol2 FROM
    MyTable Where x = @myParam1 And y = @myParam2
END
```

My Model to return result type is :

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int? myCol1 { get; set; }
    public string myCol2 { get; set; }
}
```

And my method to execute my procedure is :

```
public List<MyModel> MyProc(int? p1, string p2)
{
    var myParam1Parameter = new SqlParameter("@myParam1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = p1.HasValue ? (object)p1.Value : DBNull.Value;
    var myparam2Parameter = new SqlParameter("@myparam2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = (object)p2 ?? DBNull.Value;

    return
            _context.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>(
                "Exec [dbo].[myProc] @myParam1, @myParam2 ",
                myParam1Parameter, myparam2Parameter).ToList<MyModel>();
}
```

when run program and execute my method throw exception that shown bellow :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> ```
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@myParam1".
> ```

Comment: It's may be you made a sp before with @var parameter, Then you alter it without recreate sp class on dot net. review your sp class...

Comment: @SiamakFerdos I checked, this is not possible

Comment: Try : @myParam1 int null , May be your param1 value is null

Comment: @SiamakFerdos, i try ,but no answer. `@param1` and `@param2` has value.

Comment: Did you try calling your SP using a different syntax than this ?

Comment: Please exec your SP(using SQL editor) and give me 1 record of your output.

Comment: @HarveySpecter, no, i think that this is a standard method, you will suggest another way?

Comment: @Merta i execute it by sql editor and result is ok.

Comment: @Mohsen - Try Merta's answer. That is a valid syntax and it should work without any issues.

Comment: @HarveySpecter,i also befor test Merta's answer,i know the right way, but did not answer.i also wonder

Comment: @Mohsen test my suggested way again please

Comment: @Merta, i use sql profiler and find my problem,when exec sp add default parameters to main parameter that define in sql command and transport to sql,builded query by profiler is : `exec sp_executesql N'[dbo].[myProc] @Param1, @Param2,@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=10,@p1='x'`

Comment: @Metra, i answer by this method : `_context.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>(
                "Exec [dbo].[myProc] {0}, {1} ",
                myParam1Parameter, myparam2Parameter).ToList<MyModel>();` Can you guess wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my issue,he following should be used to define parameters :

```
var myParam1Parameter = new SqlParameter("@myParam1", SqlDbType.Int) 
{
    Value = p1.HasValue ? (object)p1.Value : DBNull.Value
};
var myparam2Parameter = new SqlParameter("@myparam2", SqlDbType.NVarChar,1)
{
    Value = (object)p2 ?? DBNull.Value
} 

return _context.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>(
            "[dbo].[myProc] @myParam1, @myParam2 ",
            myParam1Parameter, myparam2Parameter).ToList<MyModel>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try It:

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>
("[dbo].[myProc] @myParam1, @myParam2 "
,fromDateParameter, toDateParameter).ToList();
```

**(Remove "EXEC" and "ToList" from your query)**

Comment: This method was also used to test,but not result.

Comment: i use sql profiler and find my problem,when exec sp add default parameters to main parameter that define in sql command and transport to sql,builded query by profiler is : `exec sp_executesql N'[dbo].[myProc] @Param1, @Param2,@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=10,@p1='x'`