# How to Correctly Parameterize Queries

Tags: c#, sql

I am having some trouble understanding parameterizing queries, I though I got it pretty close at least but I know I'm missing something. Here's my code:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE phoneNumberData Set [Full Name]= @deviceUser, [Phone Number]= @phoneNumber, " +
                              "[Email]= @email, [Device Type]= @deviceType, [Cost Center]= @costCenter, WHERE [ID]= @id";
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@deviceUser", txtDeviceUser.Text.TrimStart());
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@phoneNumber", txtMobileNumber.Text.TrimStart());
param[2] = new SqlParameter("email", txtEmail.Text.TrimStart());
param[3] = new SqlParameter("@deviceType", txtDeviceType.Text.TrimStart());
param[4] = new SqlParameter("@costCenter", txtCostCenter.Text.TrimStart());
param[5] = new SqlParameter("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text.TrimStart()));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I was able to get my site to work without using parameters but I decided to comment that code out in place of this so that I could prevent sql injections. I'm getting a user unhandled exception: >System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@deviceUser".'

What I've done is search google and attempt to learn how to do this from other people but I don't see how mine doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me what exactly I'm missing or how parameterizing queries work so that I can fix this issue?

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance and make sure all necessary information is included in the code snippet. In particular inline all values rather than unknown values like `txtDeviceUser.Text.TrimStart()`. Also please make sure to search for error message and see if existing answers (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544411/how-to-resolved-error-must-declare-the-scalar-variable-var-in-call-stored-pro) did non address your problem.

Comment: Those parameters need to be added to the command object.  Instead of an array, just add them directly:  `cmd.Parameters.Add(...);`  Try to stay consistent: `email` is missing `@email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters have to be part of the `cmd` variable's `Parameters` collection. I also noticed an extra comma at the end of the `Set` list. Finally, for performance reasons, you will do better in many cases if you include the type information for the parameters:

```cs
cmd.CommandText = @"
    UPDATE phoneNumberData 
    SET [Full Name]= @deviceUser, [Phone Number]= @phoneNumber, 
        [Email]= @email, [Device Type]= @deviceType, [Cost Center]= @costCenter 
    WHERE [ID]= @id";

// I have to guess at type information here.
// Use the exact types and lengths from the database.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@deviceUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = txtDeviceUser.Text.TrimStart();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value =  txtMobileNumber.Text.TrimStart();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 55).Value =  txtEmail.Text.TrimStart();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@deviceType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = txtDeviceType.Text.TrimStart();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@costCenter", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = ChartxtCostCenter.Text.TrimStart();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(txtId.Text.TrimStart());
```